# Go cannot find file specified

Tags: go

I'm trying to make simple read settings from config file. Both files - config.json and Settings.go, are in the same folder. But I'm always getting `"The system cannot find the file specified."` What I'm doing wrong?

```
func GetDbConnectionString() string {
    file, err := os.Open("config.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    settings := Settings{}
    err1 := decoder.Decode(&settings)
    if err1 != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err1)
    }
    log.Print(&settings)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@/%s", settings.login, settings.password, settings.database)
}
```

[image]

Comment: you mention `settings.json`, but the file in the `Open` call is `config.json`. Is something missing?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the Go file is. What matters is the current working directory when you run your application.

Comment: @Marc, thanks for this, but it's just typo.

Comment: @andrey.shedko unless the Setting's field names beginning with lower case is also a typo you will never be able to decode your json into Settings. (Although if `Settings` implements `json.Unmarshaler` then you could. :))

Comment: @Adrian, currently app folder is in  C:\Users\andrey.shedko\go\src\github.com

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "app folder", but it's still the *working directory when you run the application* that matters. That is, what directory is CWD when you execute the binary. That is where the application will resolve relative paths based on.

Comment: @andrey.shedko are you running your app from the same folder in which `config.json` is located?

Comment: @mkopriva, yes, that's right.

Comment: Please include the exact steps you are running, including current path, directory listing, build and execution calls.

Comment: @andrey.shedko that's weird, before calling `os.Open` call `os.Getwd` and print the returned `dir` and see if it's the folder you expect.

Comment: @andrey.shedko your update suggests you need to prepend `config.json` with `settings/`. Try `os.Open("settings/config.json")`.

Comment: Regarding the question you just deleted: It probably wasn't the problem, but you did have a repeated error in that code you'll want to fix: Any time you're setting state based on state (such as in your `toggleHandler` function), you **must** use the callback form of `setState`: `this.setState(prevState => ({showPersons: !prevState.showPersons}));`. Just calling the version you pass an object into will fail sometimes because state updates are asynchronous. [Details here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `settings.json` is not in the same directory as your `main.go`. If you invoke either `go run main.go`, or `go build . && ./app`, the current path will be `.../app/` which does not contain the `settings.json` file.

Try copying your `settings.json` file to the same directory as your app, local invocation will work (it will still fail if you run from a separate directory though).

Comment: `settings.json` doesn't exist at all on that list? Did you mean `config.json`?

Comment: @MikeWarren is there a way to open file without copying it do current directory?